# I am trying to edit the inline keyboard content but it is giving me a "Cannot create property 'reply_markup' on number '91252471'

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, telegram

I am trying to increment or decrement the time when the user clicks on either the '-' or '+' button and the function should change the time accordingly. However after changing the reply_markup, it is giving me an error listed in the title.
[image: Initiate the message]

[image: Edit the message]